# I want the count to be displayed in the last storyboarding in swift

Tags: swift

I am building a survey app, where each button has a numerical value (count. I have 7 storyboards and I want the last storyboard to display the final count adding all the numerical values across all 7 stotyboards. I am not sure how to do this. is there a sample code by which I can pass this data from one storyboard to another?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to manage a static variable. In one of the classes that you use, or in a new swift class (for eg, Control.swift), add `static var count:Int = 0`.

Then, on your storyboards you can use `Control.count += ...`, and the value is available in any part of your code. In the last storyboard, you just call again `Control.count` and you have the value there.